# How to solve optimization with matrix pseudo inverse

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, matrix-inverse

Thank everybody in advance. I'd like to solve an optimization problem for a matrix function $f(C)$. However, the matrix pseudo-inverse constraint gives me big troubles.

Vectors $V_{n\times 1}$, $F_{m\times 1}$ and matrix $B_{m\times n}$ are known. Matrix $C_{n\times m}$ is unknown. How to numerically solve:
$$
\min\limits_{C}f(C)=V^T CF
$$
$$
{\rm subject\,\, to}: BC=I_{m\times m} \\
m<n
$$
$I_{m\times m}$ is an $m\times m$ Identity matrix.

I know this problem can be (sort of, because non-square matrices) formulated into linear matrix inequality (LMI). Similar to:
[optimization of inverse matrix with constraint on matrix elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162100/optimization-of-inverse-matrix-with-constraint-on-matrix-elements).
 But my processor does not allow such numerical method (LMI) to be used. Plus I do not know how to non-square LMI. So I am looking for a different approach to solve this problem.

I have an ugly gradient descent approach for this problem. But it is complicated and I do not like it. I will not post it for now to limit people's thoughts. I will post it 4 days after the question.

In addition, I'm not sure if adding following constraint would make the problem easier:
$$
{\rm subject\,\,to}: -I_{n\times n}<(CF)^T I_{n\times n}<I_{n\times n}
$$

***Appendix*** - Formulate problem to (sort of) LMI:
**(May not be correct, since matrix is not sqaure)**
Define invertible matrix $E_{n\times n}$,
$$
BC = BEE^{-1}C=(BE)(E^{-1}C)=I \\
E^{-1}C = pinv(BE) \\
C=E\,\,pinv(BE)
$$
Introducing $E$ is to represent all possible $C$ - parameterize $C$. Then the problem $\min\limits_{C}f(C)=V^T CF$ is equivalent of finding the $\min$ of scalar $\alpha$, that below inequality is feasible (i.e. some $E$ exists)
$$
V^T CF < \alpha \\
V^T E\,\,pinv(BE) F < \alpha
$$
With Schur complement, it is equivalent to following LMI
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc} BE & F\\ V^T E & \alpha \end{array}
\right]<0
$$

Comment: What is that $E$ below the min? If this is a linear space you have a linear optimization problem (objective $C\mapsto V^TCF$ is linear in $C$ and constraint $BC=I$ is linear in $C$, too).

Comment: Im assuming $F\neq 0$, otherwise the problem is trivial. If $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is in the kernel of $B$ and $V^TU \neq 0$ you can make $f(C)$ arbitrarily small by adding multiples of $u$ to a column of $C$. If there exist no such $u$ we have $V=B^TW$ for some $W\in  \mathbb{R}^m$. Then we have $f(C)=V^TCF=W^TBCF=W^TF$, i.e. $f(C)$ is independent of $C$.

Comment: @Dirk, sorry, it should be $C$ than $E$. Fixed.

Comment: @user100927, Thank you. $F\neq 0$.

Comment: Just a quick observation... With a change of variables you can assume that $B=\begin{bmatrix}I_{m\times m} & 0\end{bmatrix}$; then $C = \begin{bmatrix}I_{m\times m}\\ X\end{bmatrix}$, with an unknown $X$, without further constraints, and then the problem should be easier because it's just an unconstrained linear problem.

Comment: @federico-poloni, thank you. I assume you mean "change of basis". I will take a look to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Where is there any linear matrix inequality?